# Error: unable to start png() device in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, png, shinydashboard

I have a dashboard using R shiny dashboard with various ggplots, html tables, and valueboxes.  Everything plots and appears just fine.  However, I constantly have to close the dashboard and reopen it because it seems like if I leave it idle for too long, the next time I try to refresh the graphs I encounter the error "unable to start png() device."

This problem is fairly recent and I am not sure how it could be the code seeing as everything plots just fine as long as I use it frequently.  It also doesnt appear to be a connection issue with any of the data sets I am reading from.